# How I can give permission of written my folder in ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I create a site web in HTML and also I am using ubuntu version ubuntu 16.04 LTS  and when I read something in the editor(sublime text version 3) the system give me this message alway:
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uei1u.png)

ubuntu-16.04LTS

I am always like root in my computer  I tried these command :

```
 chmod +x jquery
   42  history
   43  clear
   44  chmod -r 775 jquery
   45  clear
   46  chmod -R a+rX *
```

and it does not working  any can help me to I give it permission to this folder

Comment: why are you always like root, is that your intention?

Comment: no , my intention is avoid use alway my password for save

Comment: Please run `ls -lF /var/www/html` and lets see who owns the files at that location!

Comment: I dont use no one server I am in the desktop

Comment: Where is your site file situated?

Comment: this is the direction of  project : . /home/sommer/Desktop/examples/jquery
 I would like give it all permission

Comment: Okm run `ls -lF /home/sommer/Desktop/examples/jquery` and add it to your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79215/discussion-between-hello-and-george-udosen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things to note here:

1. Don't run Ubuntu as root user, and definitely don't run `sublime` as root.
2. The name seen in the command line represents the following:

   - `[USERNAME]@[HOSTNAME]:[PATH][SYMBOL]`
3. To get out of `root` account use the command: `exit`, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Now in your case after chatting I decided to use the environmental variable `$USER` to change the ownership of that folder in question. So to fix that folder's permission:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/sommer/Desktop/examples/jquery
```

With that and running from the normal user account your sublime editor should be able to edit that folder contents.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6114/what-does-the-name-after-at-terminal-prompt-mean) for more.

Comment: with this command :  sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/sommer/Desktop/examples/jquery

Answer (score 0):

You should be normally operating at a regular (non-root) level user as much as possible. By always operating at the root level any new files/folders you create will be owned by root and not you. This could cause problems like you are experiencing here. Trying using 
`chown username:groupname filename` or something of the like to change the permissions and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: soluction is run this command in the terminal without  root user

Comment: sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/sommer/Desktop/examples/jquery